# Error cgi-sys/bfdenied.shtml? when

Tags: wordpress, security

When trying to access wp-admin or trying to log out I get this error `cgi-sys/bfdenied.shtml?/` + 404 page not found. The strange thing is that is happening only on my MAC OS Laptop on all browsers, even if I clear browser history. I want to mentione that I have IPV6 on this laptop. My friend from another country on a Windows 10 and IPv4 address doesn't have any issues. What could be causing this?